# How to get Microsoft Graph API Access token using ajax call

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I am using Microsoft Graph API on a SharePoint Online page to get user's events from outlook calendar. I am using ADAL.JS. When I go to that page, the page redirected to MS login to get access token from Azure AD and come to page again.

I tried to get access token using ajax call, but token does not working. I tried to call that page in iFrame on another page, but it is not getting work in iFrame.

Can you anyone suggest if I can get access token in background so that page does not redirected to Microsoft login.

We tried below code, but it is giving error as "No mailbox was found that includes the specified identity: xxxxxxx"

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {  
requestToken();  
});  
var token;    
function requestToken() {    
$.ajax({  
"async": true,  
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token", // Pass your tenant name instead of tenantname    
"method": "POST",  
"headers": {  
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
},  
"data": {  
"grant_type": "client_credentials",  
"client_id": "****************************", //Provide your app id    
"client_secret": "******************", //Provide your client secret 
"scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
},  
success: function(response) {  
console.log(response);  
token = response.access_token;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = token;
    }   
    })  
    }  
</script>  

<p id="content"></p>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test this in my online environment follow [this thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-microsoft-graph-api/), the request fail as it require user consent([official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent)).

So I grant the app Application Permissions and approve it by admin with admin consent url(https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=appid&state=12345) 
[image]

[image]

Now, I could access the calendar view by below endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/calendarView/delta?startdatetime=2018-12-04T12:11:08Z&enddatetime=2019-01-04T12:11:08Z
```

My test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            requestToken();
        });
        var token;
        function requestToken() {
            $.ajax({
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token", // Pass your tenant name instead of sharepointtechie
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                "data": {
                    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                    "client_id ": "xxx", //Provide your app id
                    "client_secret": "xxx", //Provide your client secret genereated from your app
                    "scope ": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    token = response.access_token;
                    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = token;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/calendarView/delta?startdatetime=2018-12-04T12:11:08Z&enddatetime=2019-01-04T12:11:08Z',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token+'');
                        },
                        data: {},
                        success: function (results) {                            
                            console.log(response);
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log("Error in getting data: " + error);
                        }
                    });
                }

            })
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I am able to get it now. 
Can you please let me know if I can get outlook tasks using same bearer token. 
I tried same by below URL.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks

But getting access denied error.

I also tried

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/outlook/tasks

but it says "Bad request"