# Onedrive list files in folder javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, onedrive

I am trying to list all files in a folder on my onedrive using ajax. Is there universal url for this or do I need to go through their picker?  Like google drive url for example:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='" + FOLDER_ID + "'+in+parents&pageSize=1000&key=" + API_KEY

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(function(media) {

  
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list in the specific folder of OneDrive using ajax.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, the file list is retrieved from the specific folder using Graph API. In this case, the access token is required to be used. When the access token is not used, an error like `InvalidAuthenticationToken` occurs even when the folder is publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

```js
const folderName = "### folder name ###";
const driveId = "### your drive ID ###";
const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${driveId}/root:/${folderName}:/children`;
const accessToken = "### your access token ###";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
}).done(function(media) {
  console.log(media)
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
});
```

- Also, you can retrieve the file list from the other endpoint as follows. In this case, drive id is not used.

  ```
    const folderName = "### folder name ###";
    const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/root:/${folderName}?expand=children`;
  ```

#### References:

- [Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts)
- [Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks this works. But currently I am getting access token like this:  https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=files.read&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf   which returns access token which expires in 3600. Is there a way to get access token that does not expire? If not, how could I get access token with ajax prior to making call to read onedrive folder?

Comment: @Toniq In my experience, I always retrieve the access token using the refresh token. When the refresh token is used, the access token can be retrieved. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens) About "Refresh and session token lifetime policy properties", you can see the official document. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-and-session-token-lifetime-policy-properties) If this was not useful information, I apologize.

Comment: I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327034/how-to-get-microsoft-graph-api-access-token-using-ajax-call where they seem to retrieve access token but I cant get this to work, always get 401.

Comment: @Toniq Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. About your replying, I cannot clearly answer your new issue. So, I would like to propose to post your new question as a new question. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.